# Integration with Fractional Part

Tags: integration

I am trying to compute the following integral:
in matlab notation:

```
F = int(frac(x)/(x^(1+a)),x),
```

with $0 < a < 1$,
Where frac(x) is the fractional part of $x$

Using Matlab symbolic integration, the answer was:

```
 F = -(fix(x) + a*x - a*fix(x))/(a*x^a*(a - 1))
```

Where     fix(x) = floor(x)

it's not clear whether the denominator $a(a-1)x^a$, or $a{x}^{(a(a-1))}$. I am inclined to say it's the first alternative: a*(a-1)*x^a, which would make the answer simpler.

My main objective is to compute $F$ in the interval $[0, \infty]$.

Any help to get the right answer will be much appreciated.

Comment: See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to type maths text.

Comment: It's not clear what your specific question is and if it's a math one or more of a programming one (off-topic for Math.SE). If you need to do it once, then just use `subs` on `F` returned by the symbolic integration. If your goal is compute this in floating point, then neither of your suggestions are correct. What's wrong with just using the formula given by `F` (possibly with some vectorization)?

Comment: It's a math question: Is the malab answer correct, and what is the value of the integral in [0, infinity] ?Thanks